# Image file isn't loading onto my #frame

Tags: java, jquery, html

Im trying to make an interactive portfolio page right now and I followed a tutorial from youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44pvweNCi7g&index=22&list=PLHPcpp4e3JVpXbtgyD-k-nCmwpbbMIHOh) that showed a simple java code that takes the "img" information from a thumbnail then projects it onto an overlay.

I followed everything exactly the same but for some reason the "#frame" comes out blank all the time.

```
$(function(){
    $("#portfolio img").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#frame img").attr("src", src);
        $("#frame").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

here's the java code.

```
    <div id = "overlay"></div>
    <div id = "frame"></div>
    <img src = "" alt = ""/>

<div id = "work">
        <h1>Here is my portfolio</h1>
        <p>This has some paragraphes in this</p>
        <ul id = "portfolio">
            <li><img src = "images/nxfwXYK.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
            <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and heres the Html code that contains the images.

Comment: in the code you provided, the img is not inside the `#frame`, try putting it inside `#frame`

Comment: **here's the java code.** but, where's java code? There's only JavaScript and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is outside the frame `div` so put it inside `div` as your jquery selector `$("#frame img")` indicate img is inside div :

```
<div id = "frame"><img src = "" alt = ""></img></div>
```

or use below script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#portfolio img").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#frame").next('img').attr("src", src);// use next to get image
        $("#frame").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean this:

```
<div id = "overlay"></div>
<div id = "frame">
    <img src = "" alt = ""/> // the img is now inside the #frame element
</div>

<div id = "work">
    <h1>Here is my portfolio</h1>
    <p>This has some paragraphes in this</p>
    <ul id = "portfolio">
        <li><img src = "images/nxfwXYK.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
        <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
        <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
        <li><img src = "images/demo.jpg" alt = "img"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hey ! So i put the <img src = "" alt = ""/> inside the divs and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: does it matter where the 
<div id = "overlay"></div>
<div id = "frame">
   <img src = "" alt = ""></img>
</div>

is located in the Html ?

Answer (score 1):

This will work...

```
$(function(){
    $("#portfolio img").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#frame").css("background-image", src);
        $("#frame").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first hide your blocks

```
<style>
    #overlay, #frame{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

then put img in right dom

```
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="frame">
            <img src="" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
```